# createTextFinder always finds a match in the first row when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having a problem with the createTextFinder function. It always finds a match in the first row of the sheet when it should not.

What I am trying to do is to find out if the data in an array is in the sheet and if so, copy the row with the match to another sheet and delete it from the original. However, the most important thing is that I only need to transfer the first match, i.e. if there are two elements in the sheet that appear in the search array, I only have to delete one of them and transfer them once from the original sheet to the new one.

The code I am running is:

```
function moveData(){
  let dataToSearch = [22, 10, 12];
  const date = new Date();
  dataToSearch.forEach(data => {
      let dataFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(data.toString());
      let result = dataFinder.findAll();
      if(result.length>0){
          let matchValues = sheet.getRange(result[0].getRow(), 1, 1, 5).getValues();
          for (let value in matchValues){
              found.appendRow([date, "user", matchValues[value][0], matchValues[value][1], matchValues[value][2], matchValues[value][3], matchValues[value][4]]);
              sheet.deleteRow(result[0].getRow());
          }
      }
  })
}
```

This would be the sheet without executing the code:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

As you can see in the image, only the first entries of id 22, 10 and 12 have been removed, leaving the rest on the sheet.

Any idea why it takes the first element of the sheet even though it is not in the array?

Comment: Is that a screenshot of the expected output or the resulting output after executing the current code? Because if I run your code on the exact same data, I am getting the expected output as shown in the screenshot. So I guess that is not the expected output otherwise you wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: Hi Marios, yes you are absolutely right however with other data I have from another source it was not giving me the expected result despite having the same shape as the ones I have put in the question. Your answer is correct. Thank you

Comment: Then most likely the issue had to do with the inside `for` loop. Glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

When I execute your code, I get the expected output as shown in your screenshot.

- However, since you want to remove the first match only, there is no need of using that inner `for (let value in matchValues)` loop, since you only want to delete/move **one** match only.
- Also it is not a good idea to use `appendRow` iteratively but instead append the data to an array and then use `setValues` to copy the data.

### Modified Script:

```
function moveData(){
  let dataToSearch = [22, 10, 12];     
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change that to your case
  const found = ss.getSheetByName('found'); // change that to your case
  const date = new Date();
  const found_data = [];
  dataToSearch.forEach(data => {
      let dataFinder = sheet.createTextFinder(data.toString());
      let result = dataFinder.findAll();
      if(result.length>0){
          let matchValues = sheet.getRange(result[0].getRow(), 1, 1, 5).getValues();
          found_data.push([date, "user", ...matchValues.flat()]);
          sheet.deleteRow(result[0].getRow());
      }
  });
  found.getRange(found.getLastRow()+1,1,found_data.length,found_data[0].length).setValues(found_data);
}
```